# Python, making a two dimensional list

Tags: python

Need a quick way to build a two dimensional list based on variables.
This would be the correct output

```
[[0,1,2], [3,4,5]]
```

Instead, the output im getting is...

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried

Comment: You did declare it already?! What is the point of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your example, few suggestions

```
>>> zip(*[iter(range(10))]*3)
[(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5), (6, 7, 8)]

>>> [range(n,n+3) for n in range(1,10,3)]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

>>> it = iter(range(10))
>>> [list(islice(it,3)) for _ in range(3)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Your second solution works beautifully well. Thanks m8.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions to do this.  Replace the first i with whatever filler character you want to use.

```
 l = [[i for i in range(width)] for j in range(height)]
```